# Win Server 2008 Trusted sites

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

We need to setup a trusted site on the server that will apply to all users who rdp into the server. I am look for a way to do this more systematically then require each user to set it up.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> We need to setup a trusted site on the
>   server that will apply to all users
>   who rdp into the server. I am look for
>   a way to do this more systematically
>   then require each user to set it up.

One way to do this would be to build a login script that updates the registry.  They key you are looking for is at:  (see [kb182569](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569))

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains

It is easy enough to script this with a visual basic script.

```
Option Explicit
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\example.org","2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Zoredache said, you should really split this into 2 questions.  That said, Group Policy is your solution for the first question.  Specifically **User Configuration - Policies - Windows Settings - Internet Explorer Maintenance - Security Zones and Content Ratings**.  Using this policy basically allows you to import the settings of the Security and Privacy settings on your local machine and apply them to computers who get the policy.  Trusted Sites is in the Security section.  Keep in mind, this will overwrite whatever settings are there already.

Comment: The settings overwrite, is precisely why I have to use a script in some situations.  I needed to be able to simply change the settings for that domain.